# Python string input loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking to create a python function which would iterate through a string one element at a time based on whatever the user inputs.

So let's say the list is [hello, jello, mello]. The program will print out the string then ask the user "Do you want me to read?", then "y" it'll print the first element then loop through the string until the user inputs "n", then the loop will stop.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try already? This seems like a good use case for a `for` loop

Comment: Generally, this here works with you trying to code some and when you run into problems this forum trying to help. But first, you should try yourself@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
l = ["Hello", "Jello", "Mello"]
for element in l:
    while True:
        answer = input("Do you want to read (y/n)")
        if answer.lower() == "y" or answer.lower() == "n":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
    if answer.lower() == "y":
        print(element)
    elif answer.lower() == "n":
        break
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can account for invalid inputs with a while loop that checks where or not the input is desired before the if statements. I will edit my answer to fit this.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import cycle


def print_entries_forever(list_str):
  for entry in cycle(list_str):
    answer = input('Do you want me to read [y/n]? ').lower()
    if answer.startswith('y'):
      print(entry)
    elif answer.startswith('n'):
      return


print_entries_forever(['Hello', 'Jello', 'Mello'])
```

EDIT: Loop now cycles forever until user enters 'n'.

Comment: the loop doesn't stop when you press 'n'

Comment: It didn't stop when I had pressed N, and I was looking for the loop to iterate through it more than once. Thanks though!

Comment: Thank you! Have a great day.